# How can I transform an object into a sphere?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, transforms

On YouTube I only found some solutions using geometry nodes. Therefore I would have to build the object I want to transform with geometry nodes as well.

But the object I want to transform is a highpoly model of a brick which I purchased on [Blender Market](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blender_(software)#Blender_Market). Is there maybe a modifier or some other way to round the corners, make it inflate or some other effect to turn the brick into a perfect sphere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are probably several ways to do it but you can try the *Cast* modifier:

[image]

You can also select all in Edit mode and press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> (*To Sphere*). You can save the shapes as *Shapekeys*:

[image]